# How to set QTableWidget's data

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am writting an application with PyQt. I have a list like:

```
rList = [['no','status'], ['anotherno','anotherstatus']]
```

and I have a QTAbleWidget with 2 columns. How can I set the QTableWidget's data from this list with easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

```
j=0
for i in rList:
    self.ui.myTableWidget.setItem(j, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(i[0]))
    self.ui.myTableWidget.setItem(j, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(i[1]))
    j=j+1
```

Comment: Just a code tuneup:  'j += 1' works a little better, and 'for j, i in enumerate(rList)' works even better!